# Smart Lock for Passwords not working on certain phones, error message "No eligible accounts on this device"

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-smartlockpasswords

When I run the quick-start sample from: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/

On a Nexus 6 running Marshmallow, the credentials are saved successfully.

However, on a Samsung Note 5 with Lollipop (5.1.1) I get:

```
11-25 14:45:27.581 11428-11428/com.google.example.credentialsbasic D/MainActivity: Save Failed:Status{statusCode=No eligible accounts on this device for the credentials API., resolution=null}
```

According to Google Smart Lock for Password is on by default, and I cannot find the setting for it in Samsung settings. Does this mean that Samsung phones don't support Smart Lock for Passwords? Is this a feature that will really only work on Nexuses?

I cannot find any documentation on this in terms of device support or the error message I provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight after I posted this, I found my answer.

The issue is not with the flavour of Android, but with the Google account settings. The account that I was using on the Samsung Note 5 had a custom passphrase encrypting passwords, which is not supported by Smart Lock for custom passwords.

I found the settings for Smart Lock for Passwords under a separate place from the other Smart Lock settings on the Samsung. They were under Accounts  -> Google -> scroll to very bottom:

[image]

Comment: Using Marshmallow on a Galaxy Tab E, I found the same setting under Settings > Google > Smart Lock for Passwords. Will have to direct users to ensure that this setting is On (Samsung seems to have it off by default). This was driving me nuts, thanks for the heads-up!