# Android Credentials API - No eligible accounts

Tags: android, google-api-client

I am attempting to use the Google Credentials API to store credentials for my app.  I have downloaded and installed both sample apps from here (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials) as well as tried the code in my own app.  When attempting to save any credentials I get the following error - Status{statusCode=No eligible accounts can be found, resolution=null}.

I am testing on a Nexus 5x with a single Gmail account configured.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the credentials API a google account with Smartlock enabled is required.  Smartlock is currently not supported by accounts with custom passphrase encryption (as was my issue).

In addition, disabling custom encryption does not seem to update the setting correctly on the device, and I was not willing to clear the account and re-add it to see if that fixes the problem as was suggested to me

Credit to: [Smart Lock for Passwords not working on certain phones, error message "No eligible accounts on this device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907279/smart-lock-for-passwords-not-working-on-certain-phones-error-message-no-eligib)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go to Settings > google > Smart lock passwords and turn it  on, otherwise you will not be able to user smart lock passwords