# Store Facebook Credential in Android for Google Smart Lock Password

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

Store Facebook Credential in Google Smart Lock Password

I was able to store basic username/password credentials in Smart Lock Password. There is plenty of documentation and examples for Google credentials:

```
GoogleSignInAccount gsa = signInResult.getSignInAccount();
Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(gsa.getEmail())
        .setAccountType(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
        .setName(gsa.getDisplayName())
        .setProfilePictureUri(gsa.getPhotoUrl())
        .build();
```

But so far, I was unable to store a Facebook credential. It should be something similar. But what exactly? Or is it something completely different or not supported?

```
Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(<what goes here?!>)
        .setAccountType(IdentityProviders.FACEBOOK)
        .setName(<and here?>)
        .setProfilePictureUri(<is this necessary?>)
        .build();
```

Comment: Answer by a Googler
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/issues/6#issuecomment-168844689

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I believe to be a working version of Smart Lock saving Facebook login credentials.

My app uses the FB API to login. From there I send a token to my server which in turn sends back the users email and username. I store that information like so:

```
    Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(user.getEmail())
       .setAccountType(IdentityProviders.FACEBOOK)
       .setName(user.getName())
       .build();
```

I'm not completely familiar with the Facebook API, but I think you could get the email and username from the Facebook SDK.

After using this to save the users FB credentials I am able to view them on passwords.google.com. The password shows as "With Facebook".

Comment: When you launch your app (but you're not signed in), you request credentials. Ok, When you find credential for facebook, how can you "auto" connect with the facebook sdk ?
With Google Sign in you can use Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn().

Comment: There is no background sign-in that I perform. The loader for Facebook shows as I sign the user in. If you want to avoid any visual indication that they are being signed in to perform a silentSignIn, then I'm in the same boat as you unfortunately.

Comment: @Elforama With facebook you basically have to call `registerCallback()` which will provide you with the token in `onSuccess()` this show a loading symbol on the screen but works as a sort of silentSignIn()